# bat script - only run the commands on given multiple different dates

Tags: date, batch-file, comments

In our environment we have a bat script on server (3 servers) that suppose to run on multiple given dates provided to us by the Application Support team. The current solution we are using is login to each server and comment or un-comment one particular line to have the command either run or not run. This is very tedious work and prone to us forgetting to comment it.

Is there a better solution? e.g. setting multiple dates in the script and then the script check if any of the given dates match, if it does than run the the command on certain line otherwise bypass it?

Here are the dates on which the command should run and it does not have to be in any particular format, The application team provide this date depending on their schedule every year.

May 20th
June 3rd
June 17th
July 1st
July 15th
July 29th
August 12th
August 26th
Sept 9th
Sept 23rd
Oct 7th

Any comment or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You should be a bit more specific on the date, a day/days in month/week?. You could pass the dates to check as command line arguments. Also what have you tried so far ? Code attempts are expected - we won't put more effort in your task than you..

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your comments, I have updated the question with dates. It can vary every year. We don't mind updating it once a year. Yes I don't need the code need some suggestions only at this point.

Comment: I'm thinking of else if statement.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution I have implemented and it works great at least in my situation.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Determine Today's Date
for /f %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "Get-Date -uformat '%%Y%%m%%d'"') do (
    set "currDate=%%i"
)

REM set flags as false.
SET RUNJOB=False

REM set approved dates and compare today's date to provided dates. 
if %currDate% == 20180812  set RUNJOB=True
if %currDate% == 20180826  set RUNJOB=True
if %currDate% == 20180909  set RUNJOB=True
if %currDate% == 20180923  set RUNJOB=True
if %currDate% == 20181007  set RUNJOB=True

REM if date matches then the command will run. 
if %RUNJOB%==True ( 


        REM Place the command under this line. 

                )              

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your self-answer, you could probably make it a little easier to read and maintain if you structure it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "ToDayt="
For /F %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined ToDayt Set "ToDayt=%%A"
If Not Defined ToDayt Exit /B
FindStr /X "%ToDayt%" "%0">Nul || Exit /B

Rem your commands here
Echo Today is the day
Pause

Exit /B

:: Run dates [YYYY/MM/DD]
2018/05/20
2018/06/03
2018/06/17
2018/07/01
2018/07/15
2018/07/29
2018/08/12
2018/08/26
2018/09/09
2018/09/23
2018/10/07
```

*You can just change or append to the dates as required without altering/affecting the code*

Comment: Hey compo thanks for the recommendation, nice solution as well.